# Change MP3 frequency on the fly somehow?

Tags: php, flash, audio, mp3

Does anybody know a purely PHP based way to alter the frequency of an MP3 file?

I am on shared hosting with this, so installing ffmpeg or something similar is out of the question.

If this requires actually altering the audio data, then I guess it is not possible nor feasible to do with PHP, but I was thinking maybe this is just a header setting. I don't know.

Background:

A client's website is utilizing a Flash based MP3 player to play some audio.
The client is producing the audio herself.

The trouble is that the tools that she is producing it with, and is familiar with, automatically produces MP3 files with a frequency of 48000hz, while some versions of Flash have trouble playing anything with a frequency differing from 44100khz. (See my related question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095185/embedded-flash-mp3-player-slow-on-some-files-normal-on-others)).

I would like to avoid adding yet another program to the already complex audio production process, and solve this on the web server end if possible.

Comment: PHP is not the correct tool to use to perform these kinds of operations; it's not very good, nor should it be, at decoding and reencoding these types of files. What OS is your site using? What OS is your client using? This really needs to be accomplished well before the file is downloaded to a client via the Flash player.

Comment: @David, I know. I was thinking maybe this is a file header-only operation (changing a byte or two somewhere), but as Thomas already points out, it is not, and thus it's out of the question to do that way. We're on Windows XP on the client side, and Linux on the server side but in PHP safe mode, so no `exec()`. Audacity can do the conversion nicely, I think I'll go with that.

Comment: out of interest, what tools is she using to produce the audio?

Comment: @Pekka Okay, sounds like a fair solution.

Comment: @Zeus: The Audio comes from VideoStudio 11 as a MP4, and is converted to MP3 using PowerLAME.

Comment: Changing audio sampling rate without altering the pitch or introducing distortion is a relatively CPU heavy task. The right place to do it is before mp3 conversion. I recommend http://sox.sourceforge.net, it is a cross platform command line tool that can be easily automated, creating a batch file that creates a 44.1k file when you drag a file to it is easy. "sox <in file> <out file> -r 44100" is quite a bit easier than firing up a gui and looking for menus.

Comment: After a bit more research: PowerLAME is a LAME frontend, lame accepts the following command line flag: "--resample sfreq" " sfreq = 8, 11.025, 12, 16, 22.05, 24, 32, 44.1, 48 Select  output sampling frequency". I would do a thorough check into whether PowerLAME exposes that option, and if not, maybe switch to using lame directly.

Comment: @Justin I believe http://www.dbpoweramp.com/ uses lame too, and I know you are able to adjust the bitrate using that. As you've said, this is the best place to do it.

Comment: @Justin Smith Thanks for both hints! LAME is indeed present on the system, and maybe I can write a simple batch file to do the converting.

Comment: Also, uncompressed pcm -> 48k mp4 -> 48k mp3 -> 44.1k mp3 is a lot of converting, and the fewer steps in that chain, the better your sound quality will be. Can the original software output .wav at 44.1k, rather than .mp4 at 48k?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was thinking maybe this is just a header setting.

No. That is, you can probably change it in the header, if you don't mind your MP3s being played too slow or too fast with a shifted pitch.

If you want it to sound the same, you will need to re-encode. Decoding to WAV (or raw samples), resampling, then re-encoding is a possibility, and probably your only one.

Maybe the way MP3 works allows for a shortcut (like JPEG allowing for lossless rotation), but I am unaware of any such methods.

Comment: ALl right, I thought that was the case. Thanks. Re-encoding is definitely not an option in PHP, even if somebody has been crazy enough to implement it :) I will leave the question open for some time in case somebody comes up with something I can't think of, and will otherwise accept this answer.